# Is there any way to use continueOnStepFailure with methods "waitFor" "waitForUrl"

Tags: karate

Is there any way to use **continueOnStepFailure** with methods like "waitFor" "waitForUrl"?

Presently execution stops on waitFor failure and with json syntax for continueOnStepFailure, results in null pointer exception if we give "waitFor"

```
* configure continueOnStepFailure = { enabled: true, continueAfter: true, keywords: ['match', 'status', 'waitFor'] }
```

Using Karate version 1.1.0

Comment: This is a problem in the framework. The following issue has been open and PR is pending merge: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1913

Note that 'waitFor' is not a supported configuration to to skip a step as 'waitFor' is not a *DSL* keyword. 'waitFor' is a javascript function used for convenience methods in Karate UI and is evaluated directly using javascript.

To support the use-case above you should use 'eval' as the keyword - that has been fixed in the referenced issue.

Comment: I left my thoughts on why I stated before that `waitFor()` is not part of the DSL [here](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1913#issuecomment-1030717441). I guess it's debatable but indeed it should be considered as part of the DSL.

Can you explain there why you are trying to achieve this to inform that discussion?